# MAAS: Unable to start "Commisioned" nodes

Tags: maas, dhcp, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am having problems while trying to start my first node using KVM (QEMU 2.0.0) and MAAS. Automatic detection worked fine, and during the commission (virtual machine window) I get errors such as:

```
Booting under MAAS directions...
nomodeset iscsi_target_name=(...)
maas loading amd64/generic/trusty/release/boot-kernel.....
Boot failed: press a key to retry, or wait for reset
.........
```

and

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'impi_si': no such device
Success
Success
Success
(...)
```

And after that, the virtual machine (node) turns off automatically, and the MAAS GUI shows the node as "Ready" (in green) but when trying to start it, I get this error message:

```
The action "Start selected nodes" could not be performed on 1 node because its state does not allow that action.
```

When opening the section with the properties of the node, I get this other error message:

```
You can boot this node using an adequately configured DHCP server. See https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html for instructions.
```

The DHCP server is running on the MAAS server, because the node does get its IP when booting, and it is set up on the Web GUI as well...

Any idea of why is my node not starting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably that you don't have an ssh key associated with the user yet.

Click the user name in the upper right, click preferences, add an ssh public key, then you should be able to start it.

BTW, if you "hover" over the start button on the node details page, I think it gives you this information.

Answer (score 2):

edit the node and change "Power type" to virsh.  Then you will need to add a Power address and Power ID.  The power address is the command to start the vm "qemu:///system on a local machine.  The Power ID is the name of the vm.